# Are these functions linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\psi:\Bbb R_n[x] \rightarrow \Bbb R_{n+1}[x],p(x) \rightarrow p(x^2) $

We neet to show that $\psi((p+kq)(x))=\psi(p)+k\psi(q)$ for k ∈ $\Bbb R$

I would say yes. Because: $\psi((p+kq)(x))=(p+kq)(x^2)=p(x^2)+kq(x^2)=\psi(p(x))+k\psi(q(x)) $

But the function $\phi:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R, x \rightarrow x^2$ is not linear because $\phi(kx)=(kx)^2=k^2x^2 \neq kx^2=k\phi(x) $.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p(x)$ has degree $k$, then $p(x^2)$ has degree $2k$, so your map is
$$
\psi\colon\mathbb{R}_n[x]\to\mathbb{R}_{2n}[x]
$$
Your argument is incorrect. The map sends the *polynomial* $x$ to the *polynomial* $x^2$. The fact that the map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto x^2$, is not linear is irrelevant. The map $\psi$ does
$$
\psi(a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n)=a_0+a_1x^2+\dots+a_nx^{2n}
$$
and is indeed linear, as you can now prove easily. Don't be misguided by polynomial functions, which are not the issue here.